# Proxy setting for Connecting to Xeround Database

Tags: java, database, proxy, cloud, xeround

I am trying to connect to Xeround Database fro inside my office but i cant connection it says connection link error but when i try to connect to it from home it works fine.I am not able to debug this error can anyone help

Here is my connection string:

```
 Connection con = DriverManager
    .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://instanceXXXX.db.xeround.com:XXXXX/app4XXXXXX?"
                    + "user=app4XXXXXXXX&password=XXXXXXX");
```

What proxy settings do i have to use  if any ?

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a [firewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_%28computing%29) or something that block you from accessing the specific port number while working from office. Try to telnet the port and see. You may also contact support@xeround.com for further help.